# Cómo borrar los valores de dos campos de una tabla e insertarlos en otra tabla?

Tags: php, update

estoy con la la duda de como hacer la resta de dos campos de una tabla e insertar en otra.

Tengo dos tablas1: columna1 y columna2/ tabla2 columna3 y columna4.

En tabla1 los dos campos tienen valores y la tabla2 está vacía. Quiero dejar los dos campos de tabla1 vacios e insertar el valor de la columna1 en la columna 3 de tabla2.

Podrian ayudarme con esta duda? realmente no se como hacerlo, estoy intentando con UPDATE pero la forma en que estoy escribiendo el codigo me da errores.

```
  <?php



  session_start();
  require 'funcs/conexion.php';
  require 'funcs/funcs.php';



   if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
   }

   $idcom = $_GET['idcom'];

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM  comissao_usuario  WHERE idcom = '$idcom'";
   $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
   $row = $resultado->fetch_assoc();

   ?>
```

> formulario

```
 <form class="form-inline" id="form-inline" method="POST" action="updatepagamentos.php" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="valores" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Valores</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="valores" value="<?php echo $row['valores']; ?>" >
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="valores" class="col-sm-4 control-label">AddValores</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="addvalores" value="<?php echo $row['addvalores']; ?>" >
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <input type="hidden" id="id" name="idcom" value="<?php echo $row['idcom']; ?>" />


                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="valores" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Id usuario</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="idusuario"  value="<?php echo $row['idusuario']; ?>">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="valores" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Pagamento</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" name="valorret"  >
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Guardar</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

> updatepagamento.php

No esta definido el código por que no se como hacer esta parte hasta ahora intente esto:

```
  session_start();
  require 'funcs/conexion.php';
  require 'funcs/funcs.php';



  if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
   header("Location: index.php");
  }
  $idcom= $_POST['idcom'];
  $valores = $_POST['valores'];
  $addvalores=$_POST['addvalores'];
  $valorret=$_POST['valorret'];
  $idusuario = $_POST['idusuario'];

  $sql = "UPDATE comissao_usuario INNER JOIN pagamentos SET       valores='$valores'-'$valoreret', addvalores='$addvalores', valorret='$valorret', idusuario='$idusuario'  WHERE idcom = '$idcom' ";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if($resultado){
        header("Location: welcome.php");
    }else{
        echo "erro ao salvar" . "<br>" . mysqli_error($mysqli);;
    }

   ?>
```

Comment: Pon tu codigo para poder ayudarte mejor y entender que has hecho hasta ahora

Comment: @Dariel Ramos, el codigo que realizado hasta ahora, en verdad no se como realizar esta parte lo que estoy intentando hacer es deletar los campos valores y addvalores y passarlos para otra tabla.

Comment: Si quieres restar 2 valores restalos en php y luego pon el valor en la consulta. Ejemplo en tu sql set valor = '.$valor.' y valor seria $valor = $valora - $valorb

Comment: @ Dariel Ramos , me podrias dar un ejemplo por favor?, soy nuevo en php y no se como hacerlo de forma correta